# Is the word Strawling English or American, and what does it mean?

Tags: etymology

I understood from a Jamaican lady, that she was strawling with her child down the road, ... Then I heard the same word again in Kenya - she was strawling along a street in Nairobi. What is the origin of this word? And what is the accurate meaning. The spelling control doesn't accept it :-)

Comment: Sounds like they were saying "strolling". It means walking slowly or leisurely.

Comment: Agreed. I think she was saying "strolling" with a thick Jamaican accent, mon.

Comment: Was it the *same* Jamaican lady you found ['strolling'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=strolling&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BLtaWcO-BIrjvgSsgaWYCw) with her child down the street in Nairobi? They must have gone there on vacation, methinks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect she might have said "strolling". It means to "walk leisurely" according to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/strolling). From [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stroll) it seems that the word:

> [comes] from dialectal German strollen, variant of Swiss German strolchen "to stroll about, loaf," from Strolch "vagabond, vagrant," also "fortuneteller," perhaps from Italian astrologo "astrologer."